# How to decode geohash using python in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, data-science, geocode

I need code to decode geohash in python. There's a column which contains geohashes. I need them decoded into latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [pygeohash](https://pypi.org/project/pygeohash/) from pypi using pip

```sh
$ pip install pygeohash
```

Then add a new column to the dataframe with the latitude and longitude

```py
import pygeohash as pgh
# ...
# location is a new column filled with (lat, lon) tuples
df['location'] = df.apply(lambda rec: pgh.decode(rec['geohash']), axis=1)
```

Here `'geohash'` is the column which contains geohashes.

Comment: It is so slow. I already tried it and even after 20 minutes it didn't show any output. Any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

this solution is performant:

```
import pygeohash 
import numpy as np 

def dehashingit(x): 
    """
    this returns a tuple, where at index 0 is the lats and at index 1 is the longs
    """
    return pygeohash.decode(x)

func = np.vectorize(dehashingit) 

location = func(df.geohash.values)

df['lat'], df['long'] = location[0], location[1]
```